# Where am I going wrong in this AM-GM ineguality problem?

Tags: inequality

**Q:** *When is the perimeter of a triangle minimum for a given area?*
This is how I went about it:

---

Let the sides of the triangle be $a$, $b$ & $c$.

> $s = \dfrac{a+b+c}{2}$
>   By AM-GM inequality,
>   $\dfrac{s+(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)}{4}\ge \sqrt[4]{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ ---$({1})$
>   Since $\sqrt[4]{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ is constant(say $k$),
>   Therefore, min. value of $\dfrac{s+(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)}{4}$ is $k$.
>   i.e. min. value of $a+b+c$ is $4k$
>   But for this equality must hold in $(1)$, which is only possible when
>   $s = (s-a) = (s-b) = (s-c)$
>   But this implies that $a=b=c=0$ which is surely not true.

---

So, can you point out where precisely the error is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dfrac{s+(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)}{4}\ge \sqrt[4]{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, not $\le$.

Comment: There is no error. The value $4k$ is unachievable, therefore it's not
 the minimum. You've successfully found that $a+b+c>4k$.

Comment: s depends on a, b, and c. (s+(s-a)+...)/4 = (4s-2s)/4 = s/2.

Comment: As far as I know, the perimeter of a triangle _is_ minimum for a given area when the triangle in equilateral.!?

Comment: @user236182 the value of k is not unreachable. k is easily calculated since the area is given as a parameter and therefore $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ is known.

Answer (score 1):

Someone's been pulling your leg - this is a trick question. The perimeter of a triangle of a given area $S$ is unbounded! Indeed, for any $P>0$, we can construct a triangle whose area is $S$ and whose perimeter is greater than $P$.

Consider a triangle whose base is of length $P$ and whose height is $\frac{2 S}{P}$. Its area is
$$
\frac{height \cdot base}{2} = \frac{\frac{2 S}{P} \cdot P}{2} = S.
$$
But since it has an edge of length $P$, its perimeter is surely greater than $P$.

Comment: I have corrected the question. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a right triangle
with sides
$n, 1/n, \sqrt{n^2+1/n^2}$.
This has area $\frac12$
and perimeter greater than
$2n$.

However,
on a sphere,
the perimeter and the area of triangles
are bounded.

Comment: I have corrected the question. Thanks nevertheless.